# Format reference to item in sublist

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, labels, enumitem

I use the `enumitem` package for my lists. To lighten up I only display the item of the current list but I would like the reference to show all structure needed to not confuse the item I reference to with another which has the same sublist-reference. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\bfseries\arabic*.}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\bfseries\alph*)}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item first big item
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item first little item of the first big item
            \item second little item of the first big item\label{second-little-of-first-big}
        \end{enumerate}
        \item second big item
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item first little item of the second big item
            \item second little item of the second big item\label{second-little-of-second-big}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}

I like this display (because it's light), but when I want
to refer to the first reference or to the second, it is
displayed by \ref{second-little-of-first-big} and
\ref{second-little-of-second-big}, and I would like it to be
refered by \textbf{1.b)} and\textbf{ 2.b)}.
\end{document}
```

Which makes :

[image]
I know I can put something like `\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumi.\theenumii.}` but I don't want to display all the numbers of the imbricated lists in the list, I want it only in the references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially you can format the reference like you did with the label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\bfseries\arabic*.}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\bfseries\alph*)},ref={\bfseries\theenumi\alph*)}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item first big item
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item first little item of the first big item
            \item second little item of the first big item\label{second-little-of-first-big}
        \end{enumerate}
        \item second big item
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item first little item of the second big item
            \item second little item of the second big item\label{second-little-of-second-big}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}

I like this display (because it's light), but when I want
to refer to the first reference or to the second, it is
displayed by \ref{second-little-of-first-big} and
\ref{second-little-of-second-big}, and I would like it to be
referred by \textbf{1.b)} and \textbf{2.b)}.
\end{document}
```

[image]